# How to add dynamic control to extended GridView that persists past OnPreRender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am extending the default GridView WebControl class. I am adding functionality to this extended class that adds a LinkButton at the bottom of the GridView. It is not adding it in the table DOM. The LinkButton would be a sibling to the table. I am able to add it after PreRender, but it has no OnClick event handlers.

After some looking, I figured it needs to be added in the overrided OnInit method of the extending GridView class. Here's the code I have (as a sample):

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn += SomeClick_Click;

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

I place a breakpoint in OnInit and one in OnPreRender. When I step through, the LinkButton is added to the GridView's Controls collection once

```
    base.OnInit(e);
```

is called. The problem is, once the application invokes OnPreRender, the added Control is dropped and all I'm left with in the collection is the normal ChildTable control.

**Problem:** I expect to see two child Controls in the collection when OnPreRender is invoked: the added control and the default control. Ideally, the added control should appear after the default control in the collection.

I've tried using the AddedControl(Control control, int index) method and it showed no promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hours of working on this, I decided to go through the .NET source code. For anyone interested, you can find it here if you have not already: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

The problem (which is not really a problem just that I didn't know) is that CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding) is invoked. Some where before that method is called, the Controls collection is emptied. This method gets called before PreRender and after OnInit for the control. It is in this method that the ChildTable is added.

**The solution:**

1. Remove the adding of the child control in OnInit (no need to override)
2. Add the creation of the child Control in CreateChildControls(..., ...) after the ChildTable is created. For me, I allow the default behavior (base.CreateChildControl(...)) to run, then do my custom logic.
3. If you do this, the event handling will work as expected

   ```
   protected override int CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
   {
       int result= base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

       LinkButton btn = new LinkButton() { Text = "Test" };
       this.Controls.Add(btn);

       btn.Click += button_Click;

       return result;
   }
   ```